# Primitive elements of an extension L/K and the K-embedding's of L

Tags: field-theory

I was studying for my preliminary exams and found this problem on a previous exam. I think I proved the forward implication, but I am having trouble proving the converse statement. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Let $L/K$ be a seperable extension of degree n and $φ_1,φ_2,…,φ_n$ be distinct $K$-embeddings of $L$ into some splitting field for $L$. Prove that $a\in L$ is primitive if and only if the images $φ_1(a),φ_2(a),…,φ_n(a)$ are distinct.

Proof. Suppose that $a∈L$ is primitive. Then $L=K(a)$, so $L/K$ has basis $\{1,a,…,a^{n−1}\}$, and furthermore any $K$-embedding of $L$ will be completely determined by where $a$ is mapped to. Now suppose that $φ_i(a)=φ_j(a)$ for some $i≠j$. Then $φ_i=φ_j$ for all $x∈L$ which contradicts our hypothesis that each $φ_i$ is distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your proof of the forward implication.

For the converse, since $L/K$ is separable, $a\in L$ is separable, so the number of distinct images it has under all $K$-embeddings of $L$ into an algebraic closure of $K$ is equal to its degree over $K$.  Thus if any of the $L$-embeddings map $a$ to the same image, its degree over $K$ is less than $n$, so it can't generate $L$.

Comment: That makes sense. It doesn't explicitly show that $a$ is primitive, but it follows that $[K(a):K]=n,$ and since $K(a)\subset L$ we have $K(a)=L.$